# Отмена css-правила через :not

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте. Вот такая история. Прописал в стилях

```
p { text-indent:1em}
```

чтобы абзацы были с отступом. Но вот беда, тег img тоже находится в теге p и растянутая на всю ширину экрана картинка "некрасиво" сдвигается на 1em.
Почему-то ничего не получается сделать. Пробовал

```
p:not(img) {text-indent:0em;}
```

и поигрался с этой конструкцией.

Однако, ничего не получается.
Каким образом можно отменить отступ для абзацев, где первый дочерний элемент img?

Comment: CSS не может взять родительский элемент. Для этого нужно использовать JS. А вы пробовали прописать обратное картинкам?
p img { text-indent: initial}

Comment: Если не особо мудрить, то можно элементы <img> внутри параграфа сделать блочными:
`p img:first-child {
    display: block;
}`

Comment: @Deonis, огромное спасибо. Никогда бы ни догадался. Сделайте комментарий ответом!!! Сработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не особо мудрить, то можно элементы `<img>` внутри параграфа сделать блочными:

```
p img:first-child { display: block; }
```

<sup>║ Скопировано из [комментария](/questions/440489/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-not?rq=1#comment462709_440489) пользователя [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Что здесь происходит?**

Вы ставите `p` и *всем строчным наследникам* `text-indent: 1em`. Ваши изображения - это *наследники* `p`, которые наследуют `text-indent: 1em`.

**Почему не работает конструкция с not?**

По вышеописанным причинам: вы пытаетесь применить not к элементу, в то время как реальная работа должна производиться с его наследниками. `p:not(img)` - ну право дело, где вы видели `p`, который в то же время был бы `img`?

**Что же делать?**

Работать с изображениями, лежащими внутри этого `p`:

```
p img {
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы ошиблись. text-indent прописан именно к p, ваше правило не отменяет отступ у абзаца. Я жду когда @Deonis сделает комментарий ответом - все получилось. Про not я понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Deus у абзаца и не должно отменять.

Comment: вопрос касался именно абзацев

Comment: ага, втупил, хотя в общем-то выше все равно более верное решение, чем гоняться за отдельными абзацами с img